# Scrapy playwright non-headless browser always closing

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, scrapy-playwright

I am scrapping a website using Python Scrapy framework together with scrapy-playwright plugin. Headless is set as False. I would like to have my framework-controlled browser not to close after the run in order for me to check the webpage it's displaying after invoking some actions on the page. I suppose there is some setting which make it possible however I am not able to find it in the docs. Does anyone know anything?

BR

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your code? Changes are, you can slap a big timeout after your work to keep it open, or avoid calling `browser.close()` (unless Scrapy calls it for you). You can also snap a screenshot at the end of the action to see what the general state is for validation.